# Firebase Simple Login iOS Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios7, firebase

I've implemented Firebase Simple Login for iOS in my iPhone app on a iOS 7 Only app.

This is the code called when a user attempts to login,

```
[self.authClient loginToFacebookAppWithId:kFacebookAppID permissions:@[@"email"]
                            audience:ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe
                 withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, FAUser *user) {
                     if (error != nil) {
                         // There was an error logging in
                         NSLog(@"Error FB Login");
                         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:NO];
                         [self showErrorAlertViewWithText:@"You aren't logged into Facebook on your Phone. Please go to your iPhone Settings->Facebook and login"];
                     } else {
                         // We have a logged in facebook user
                         NSLog(@"Facebook Login Successful");

                         //Time to check if its a new user or old one
                         [self checkIfNewUserOrOldWithUserId:user];

                     }
                 }];
```

- authClient is a FirebaseSimpleLogin class object which is initialized for sure
- I've tried with both FacebookSDK implemented and removed (the FirebaseSimpleLogin library is supposed to fall-back then)
- I am testing on a real device

What the problem is, this only works if a user is logged into Facebook on the iOS system Facebook integration. If a user isn't logged in, and the Facebook app is installed, the user is diverted to that, but when the user approves, and my app opens up again, the completion block is never called.

Even if Facebook App isn't installed, then Facebook opens in safari, and if i login to facebook from safari and give a go-ahead for my app, and when my app opens, the completion block isn't called.

Adding or removing the FacebookSDK to the app doesn't make any difference.

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] We're aware of some compatibility issues with the Simple Login iOS client and the Facebook SDK, but should have them resolved in the next 24 hours. I'll report back here when fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase recently released Simple Login v1.3.1 for iOS, and you can download the latest version at https://cdn.firebase.com/ios/FirebaseSimpleLogin.framework-LATEST.zip.

TO get up and running with Firebase Simple Login and the Facebook SDK on iOS, there are a few things that you'll need to do:

1. In your `.plist` file, you must have the 'FacebookAppID' and 'FacebookDisplayName' keys set to your Facebook application id and display name, and they should match your Facebook app settings exactly.
2. In your `AppDelegate.m` file, you must handle redirects from Facebook to your application:

`

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

// your code here ...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    // add any app-specific handling code here
    return wasHandled;
}

@end
```

**Note**: This assumes that you have Firebase and the Firebase Simple Login frameworks in your application already, if you need instructions, see https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-quickstart.html.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank You! Yes, that fixed my problem. I was under the impression that Firebase was handling everything, but realized i still had to write the above method for the FB callback in my App Delegate. I see you guys have added it to your docs/guide as well. =)